# Dynamically loading multi-tab iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to create a multi-tab application that has a tab that will load based off a choice made at a menu in the beginning?

For example, if someone picked "tic tac toe" at the beginning menu, a "game" tab would load a tic tac toe screen instead of a chess or checkers screen.

If this is not clear, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the tab bar in code and then you just insert the appropriate game controller depending on what the user selects before you push the tab bar to screen.

Or

Have the users decision persisted and on loading the game tab have it query which game the user selected. `NSUserDefaults would be an easy way to persist which game was chosen.